# Value was either too large or too small for a UInt64.'

Tags: c#

My codes are like below. 
I just want to try to convert number to *binary* and summarize *binary numbers* as if they are *decimal* ones, e.g. the desired outcome for `3` is `22`:

```
1 ->  1
2 -> 10
3 -> 11
-------
     22 == 1 + 10 + 11
```

But number array is *growing* and the code *blowing* :)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    long deger = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    {
        deger *= (deger + 1);
        int result = solve(deger);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}

public static int solve(long a)
{
    ulong[] lastValue = new ulong[a];
    for (int i = 1; i < a; i++)
    {
        var binary = Convert.ToString(i, 2);
        lastValue[i] = Convert.ToUInt64(binary);// this part gives an error
    }

    var result =  lastValue.Aggregate((t, c) => t + c);

    return (int)result;
}
```

Comment: you treat *binary* e.g. `0b100 == 4` as a *decimal* `100` then convert it to *binary* `100 -> 0b1100100` which you again treat as *decimal* `1100100` etc.

Comment: What is the initial problem, please? What is the puzzle you trying to solve?

Comment: My problem is

Converting each number of 1 to N into binary and summarize all of them separately

For Example;
`1 = 1 ; 2 = 10 ; 3 = 11 ; Sum = 22` imagine it goes big number

Answer (score 1):

Well, `UInt64` is not *large enough*; you can try either `BigInteger` or you may sum up `string`s:

```
private string MyBinarySum(string left, string right) {
  var x = left
    .PadLeft(Math.Max(left.Length, right.Length) + 1, '0')
    .Reverse()
    .Select(c => c - '0')
    .ToArray();

  var y = right
    .PadLeft(Math.Max(left.Length, right.Length) + 1, '0')
    .Reverse().Select(c => c - '0')
    .ToArray();

  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(left.Length);

  int shift = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; ++i) {
    int v = x[i] + y[i] + shift;

    shift = v / 2;
    v = v % 2;

    sb.Append((char)('0' + v));
  }

  return String.Concat(sb.ToString().TrimEnd('0').Reverse());
}
```

Then, with a help of *Linq*

```
   var result = Enumerable
    .Range(0, 1000000)
    .Select(item => Convert.ToString(item, 2))
    .Aggregate((sum, item) => MyBinarySum(sum, item));

   Console.Write(result);
```

**Outcome:**

```
111010001101010010010101110011011100000
```

which is *beyond* `UInt64.MaxValue == 18446744073709551615`

Answer (score 0):

Look at `UInt64.MaxValue` and `UInt64.MinValue`.

They defined as `18446744073709551615` and `0` corresponding.